# Relation of standard deviation between independent and dependent variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, integral

Is there a relationship between the standard deviation of an independent variable to the standard deviation of a dependent variable? For example, if we know the standard deviation of a variable $x$ called $\sigma_x$, and we know the relationship $y(t) = \int x(t) dt$, is it possible to obtain $\sigma_y$?

I have tried deriving an equation based on a random walk process $\sigma_y = \sqrt{n}*\sigma_x$ where $n$ is the number of steps (samples), but I do not think this is correct after comparing it with another example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is yes.  Whether it is easy to get the answer in closed form, or whether one must settle for a numerical answer depends a lot on the distribution and the function.

I am presuming you are looking at a Random Variable $X$ with a known distribution over a fixed time (say, one year) that does not change with $t$, such as a normal distributed as $N(1,2)$, but scales with $n$, where n is the number of sub-intervals: $X~N(\frac{1}{n},\frac{\sigma}{{\sqrt n}})$  Then the integral you have asked for is the standard Arithmetic Brownian Motion, I believe.

Whether one can easily calculate such functions where integrals are there is, in general, the study of Stochastic Differential Equations.

Comment: Not sure I'm getting it. Essentially what I have is the standard deviation of a force response over time ($\sigma_F$) and I want to get the standard deviation of position ($\sigma_x$). We know that $F=ma$ and we can integrate this equation twice to get the position $x$. I'm wondering how $\sigma_F$ is related to $\sigma_x$.

Comment: I'm looking for a shortcut.  Do you know the distribution type of the force?  Is it a normal RV?  Ultimately yes, you can do it, but it would be nice to (1) avoid having to integrate the actual density function or (2) see some way to do this from first principles that is clever.